# Copying the text inside a div into clipboard upon clicking the div

Tags: javascript

I've got a couple of `div`s containing paragraphs of text. What I'm trying to achieve is to copy the content of the paragraph into my clipboard upon clicking the `div`.

Note that the `div`s act as clickable buttons in this case.

I could make this work with buttons containing text, however I'm struggling to make this work with `div`s.

```
<div class="parent">

        <div class="child">
            <p>Text A.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="child">
            <p>Text B.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="child">
            <p>Text C.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The script should be exactly the same for BUTTONs and DIVs. What have you tried? Where is the struggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use somthing like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("btn");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.textContent)
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that this has limited support (not supported in IE and Edge etc.): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
function  copy(btn) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(btn.innerText)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child" onclick="copy(this)" >
            <p>Text A.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="child" onclick="copy(this)" >
            <p>Text B.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="child" onclick="copy(this)" >
            <p>Text C.</p>
        </div>
</div>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a `<textarea>` element to be appended to the document. Set its value to the string that we want to copy to the clipboard.

2.Append said`<textarea>` element to the current HTML document.

3.Use `HTMLInputElement.select()` to select the contents of the  element.

4.Use`Document.execCommand('copy')` to copy the contents of the  to the clipboard.

5.Remove the  element from the document.